# Gradle 2.0.0+ Application takes 7_8 seconds and more time to start

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex, android-instant-run

I am working on an application which is/was working perfectly fine with Gradle 1.5.0. After the introduction of 2.0.0 and Instant run features, i updated my build.gradle to 2.0.0/2.1.0.

I have started facing an issue where my application splash screen stucks for around 7_8 seconds and then onCreate of SplashActivity is called.

Also i am setting

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```

but the user stocks there for longer time. For all my release versions i have to switch back to Gradle 1.5.0 where everything works fine.

My Application Class extends MultidexApplication,does this issue has something to do with it ?

Here are some logs which i could gather from console.

```
06-05 20:30:58.168 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.GetIt.debug-1/lib/arm
<===============Stucks here for long time ============>

06-05 20:31:36.324 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.GetIt.debug-1/lib/arm
06-05 20:31:36.405 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
06-05 20:31:36.405 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug I/MultiDex: install
06-05 20:31:36.405 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
06-05 20:31:36.405 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug I/MultiDex: install
06-05 20:31:36.405 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
06-05 20:31:36.730 21611-21611/com.GetIt.debug I/GAv4: Google Analytics 8.2.98 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                                         adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                                         adb logcat -s GAv4
```

Comment: Instant run is still buggy, can you confirm that disabling Instant run via your settings in Android Studio solves this issue or not